# How do I set a default value for a combo box that draws values from a table/query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Since I'm new to Access but it is what I have available, I am customizing a database template to fit my needs.  The template came with a table called "Donations" that records all the received money from contributors.  I have added another table called "Descriptions" that has labels for the common types of contributions we receive (Donation, Participant, Sponsor, Anonymous, Memorial, Honorarium).

In the "Donation" table I have added a combo box called "Label" that imports the values from "Description" to populate the list.

```
SELECT Descriptions.ID, Descriptions.Label 
FROM Descriptions ORDER BY Descriptions.[Label];
```

This lookup is working correctly.

Since most of the contributions we receive fall under the Description/Label of Donation, in the name of efficiency, I would like to set this to be the default value.  However, I have no idea how to do this.

Failed Methods:

`"Donation"` - Error 'Type mismatch' in the default value.
`[Donation]` - Could not find field "Donation"
`[Description].[Label]` - Could not find field "Description].[Label".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your lookup query `SELECT Descriptions.ID, Descriptions.Label` includes the ID, I assume the ID is what is internally stored.

Open your `Descriptions` table, find the ID of "Donation", and use that number as `Default value` in the main table.